# Error in CakePHP after changing path of Index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP project and have encountered a problem. 
We've written an Ajax function that sends data to a php function that adds a folder (in german: ordner) to a corresponding database. It worked perfectly fine but we wanted to move the index.ctp for the "Ordners" to the "Pages" directory so that it is our main page. Now the function still works but it puts out the error message from the Ajax function when clicking the button nonetheless. We have written different functions and the same thing happens there too.

Code from the Javascript:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cake1/ordners/add',
        data: sendData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //alert(sendData);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

add function from the OrdnersController:

```
public function add() {
    $ordner = $this->Ordners->newEntity();


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $ordner = $this->Ordners->patchEntity($ordner, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Ordners->save($ordner)) {
            //$this->Flash->success(__('Your folder has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your folder.'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $ordner);
}
```

routes.php

```
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It worked perfectly fine but we wanted to move the index.ctp for the "Ordners" to the "Pages" directory so that it is our main page.

This doesn't make any sense. Also it would be smart to tell us what the error is that you now get. However, it doesn't matter. Instead of moving the view point the router to the index of your orders controller:

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'index']);
```

And your home page / will route to the controller. There is a reason why code is put in specific folders. It doesn't make sense to move a non-static page into the folder of the Pages controller which is by default a controller that serves static pages. The view will be out of context. While this technically could work, it doesn't make sense from a logical and best practice point of view. Think of view + controller + model as separated modules that are logically grouped together. I guess you'll agree that it doesn't make sense to put for exampl the users index into a products folder. ;)